# ngrx + marble testing + delay

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

Let's say I have an effect

```
@Effect()
someEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(X), switchMap(() => 
of(Y).pipe(delay(3000)))
```

How should marble test look like?

```
const action = new X();
const result = new Y();

actions$.stream = hot('-x', { x: action });
const expected = cold('-y', { y: result }); // ? adding frames or 3s doesn't work
expect(effects.someEffect$).toBeObservable(expected);
```

In return I get

```
Expected $.lenght = 0 to equal 1.
```

Comment: This is a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427965/react-redux-observable-timeout-marble-testing. You basically have to pass scheduler to `delay`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

If you dont want to pass scheduler to delay you can also do sth like:

```js
import { cold, hot, getTestScheduler } from "jasmine-marbles";

const scheduler = getTestScheduler();
scheduler.run(helpers => {
  const action = new X();
  const result = new Y();

  actions$ = helpers.hot('-x', { x: action });
  helpers.expectObservable(effects.someEffect$).toBe('- 3s y', { y: result });
})
```